# python elasticsearch: how to query a string on all fields

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-py

I have the following python code which works fine, bringing me exactly 50 results as expected:

```
elastic = settings.ELASTIC
indexes = u'nginx-access-2769z-2018.11.26.16'
filter_by_client = [
    {'match_phrase': {'client_id': '2769z'}},
]
range_for_search = {
    'gte': str(1543248611),
    'lte': str(1543249511),
    'format': 'epoch_second',
}
query_body = {
    'from': 0,
    'size': 50,
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': filter_by_client,
            'filter': {'range': {'@timestamp': range_for_search}},
        },
    }
}
search_result = elastic.search(index=indexes, body=query_body)
results = [result['_source'] for result in search_result['hits']['hits']]
```

And I now if I add another filter such as

```
...
filter_by_client = [
    {'match_phrase': {'client_id': '2769z'}},
    {'match': {'remote_address': '181.220.174.189'}}
]
...
```

It also works fine! Narrowing it down to 5 results.

My problem is: how do I query that string over **all fields**? Doesn't matter to me if that string is at the start/end of the field, if it is uppercase, if the field is actually an integer/float and not a string, ...

Already tried using the "_all" keyword like this

```
...
filter_by_client = [
    {'match_phrase': {'client_id': '2769z'}},
    {'match': {'_all': '181.220.174.189'}}
]
...
```

but it gives me 0 results. Trying to reproduce the same behaviour that happen over Kibana interface.

Comment: As mentioned in elasticsearch documentation `_all` is [deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html). Use [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) instead and query on the custom field indexed by using `copy_to` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Nishant mentioned is the best solution using `copy_to` field, however if you don't have a control in changing your mapping, then you can try and see if any of the below approaches help.

### Using Query String Query

You can make use of [Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) where your query would be as follows:

```
...
filter_by_client = [
    {'match_phrase': {'client_id': '2769z'}},
    {'query_string': {'query': '181.220.174.189'}}
]
...
```

One important note is that `query_string` searches by default all the fields. The link I've mentioned states the below:

> The default field for query terms if no prefix field is specified.
>   Defaults to the index.query.default_field index settings, which in
>   turn defaults to *. * extracts all fields in the mapping that are
>   eligible to term queries and filters the metadata fields.

Also I am mentioning this because I want you to understand the difference in using query_string vs simple match [Match vs Query-String](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) before you decide to go for query_string.

> The match family of queries does not go through a "query parsing"
>   process. It does not support field name prefixes, wildcard characters,
>   or other "advanced" features. For this reason, chances of it failing
>   are very small / non existent, and it provides an excellent behavior
>   when it comes to just analyze and run that text as a query behavior
>   (which is usually what a text search box does). Also, the
>   phrase_prefix type can provide a great "as you type" behavior to
>   automatically load search results.

### Using multi-match

The below another possible solution, if you are not wanting to change the mapping, which makes use of [multi-match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) queries

```
...
filter_by_client = [
    {'match_phrase': {'client_id': '2769z'}},
    {'multi_match': {'query': '181.220.174.189', 'fields': ['url', 'field_2']}}
]
...
```

See how you need to explicitly mentioned the fields to be considered while querying. But do make sure you validate/test it thoroughly.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I'll look into this option of using `copy_to`, but for know I'll go with your suggestion. Thanks!!